# How long will a concrete bore plug take to cure?

Tags: concrete

I have sealed an old abandon deep boring which was 220 feet long. First I poured small stone chips up to 7 feet and poured liquid cement mixed with Dr fixit up to 220 feet. My boring had PVC cashing which was 100 feet long. Please let me how long it will take to dry the cement to become fully concrete.

Comment: What is "liquid cement" and what is "Dr. Fixit"? Don't those products' literature give you cure times? What level of cure are you asking about?

Comment: "Fully concrete" is pretty subjective.  Why do you need to know when it's fully cured?  Does it need to support some weight or what?

Comment: About 24 years. The point of maximum strength is achieved much sooner.

Comment: Not sure what you a talking about Mousam.  By bore do you mean a hole in the ground that is 220 **deep** ??  Please give us a more detailed description.  PVC 100 feet long ?

Comment: Cured well enough for what purpose?  It's not like a driveway or a sidewalk where you will have traffic or people walking on it.  This is presumably to plug the well.  At this point it's completed if you ask me.  Concrete gets quite hard in a relatively short period of time and cures to about 50% of it's final strength in a week or so.  Beyond 30 days it gets only marginally stronger over time.

Comment: I am not sure how well a plug like that will hold in pvc. there may be some legal issues as a bad seal could contaminate the ground water in the area, I would want to check regulations or you might find when a neighbor gets sick and then another they trace it to your “hole” you end up in court for there health issues. Igus happened about a block away from me where a home owner drilled his own water well and did not seal it properly, he had a filter system that kept his family safe but one of the neighbors almost died then when another got sick the county tested several wells finding the well